# Router slim not working

Tags: frameworks, router, slim

I'm trying to use the [Slim FrameWork](http://www.slimframework.com/) following documentation for the same, set up mod_rewrite and installed mcryp;

If I call `http://localhost/slim/books` got: Not Found

If I call `http://localhost/frame/index.php?books` works!

What could this be.

This happens for the slim and flight, but does not happen to Laravel.

Here my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}!-F 
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ / Index.php [QSA]
```

I'm using:

Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu 04.14)

PHP Version 5.5.15RC1

Anyone know what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file change `Index.php` to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

**create an .htaccess file**

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

Case while running

1. To run file example myproj/file.php
   $app->get('/',function() {
   });

   localhost/myproj/file.php
2. $app->get('/nam',function() {
   });

   localhost/myproj/file.php/nam

you can also use postman

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en